# New-ADUser with Splatting errors

Tags: windows, active-directory, powershell

I am getting an error when trying to run the following snippet.

```
$Users = Import-Csv -Path $Path            
foreach ($User in $Users)            
{
    $Domain = "Domain.lan"
    $DefaultPassword = 'Password123'
    $Parms = @{'Name'= "$($User.Lastname), $($User.Firstname) $($User.middleinitial)";
               'DisplayName' = "$($User.Firstname) $($User.Middleinitial) $($User.LastName)";
               'samAccountName' = "$($User.Firstname[0])$($User.middleinitial)$($User.Lastname)".ToLower();
               'UserPrincipalName' = "$($User.Firstname[0])$($User.middleinitial)$($User.Lastname)@domain.lan".ToLower();
               'GivenName' = $User.Firstname;
               'Surname' = $User.LastName;
               'Initials' = $User.middleinitial;
               'EmailAddress' = $User.EmailAddress;
               'AccountPassword' = (ConvertTo-SecureString $DefaultPassword -AsPlainText -Force);
               'Enabled' = $true;
               'Path' = "OU=Users,DC=domain,DC=lan";
               'ChangePasswordAtLogon' = $True;
               'PasswordNeverExpires' = $false
        }

    if (Get-ADObject -Filter { samAccountName -eq "$($Parms.samAccountName)"})
    {
        Write-Error "The user $($Parms.SAMAccountName) is already a user in $Domain"
    }
    else
    {
        $Account = New-ADUser $Parms -PassThru
    }
```

The error that I get is:

```
New-ADUser : The name provided is not a properly formed account name
At C:\Tools\Scripts\Add-BatchUsers.ps1:34 char:9
+         New-ADUser $Parms
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (CN=System.Colle...DC=Domain,DC=lan:String) [New-ADUser], ADException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:1315,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.NewADUser
```

However using the same $Parms if I specify each parameter the command works as expected. Can anyone explain this behavior?

Comment: Seems inconsistent that sometimes first name is `$User.Firstname` but other times `$User.Firstname[0]`. Is is a string or is it an array of strings?

Comment: PowerShell strings are defined as an array. You can have an array of strings but in this instance $User.Firstname is only one item. PowerShell allows me to index into this string as it's handled as an array of characters. so if $User.Firstname = "SomeName" $User.FirstName[0] would result in "S"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you splat you have to express the variable as `@Params` at the call site, not `$Params`

Comment: I knew this. It's so easy to get caught up in the other details.

Comment: No worries man, did it myself the other day.